# Insert array into another array based on if command - putting it in wrong place

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
    'reportDescription' => array(
        'reportSuiteID' => 'globretailprod',
        'elements' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => $queryElement
            )
        ),
        'metrics' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => $queryMetric
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I'm trying to insert some code into the array using an if command. This is what I have:

```
if (isset($querySegment)) {
    $arr['reportDescription']['segments'] = $querySegment;
}
```

However that gives me the wrong result, what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
{
                "reportDescription": {
                                "reportSuiteID": "rbsglobretailprod",
                                "dateFrom": "2018-09-09",
                                "dateTo": "2018-09-10",
                                "dateGranularity": "day",
                                "metrics": [{
                                                "id": "pageviews"
                                }],
                                "elements": [{
                                                "id": "page"
                                }],
                                "segments": [{
                                                "id": "jjj"
                                }]
                }
}
```

Notice there are two issues with this. Firstly, segments isn't isn't insert with an id, it's just inserted as a value. Secondly, I am a bit concerned about the trailing comma after metrics in my original array, since I need to be able to add a comma after the metrics array if I do include segments.

Comment: Use `$arr['reportDescription']['segments'] = ["id" => $querySegment]`

Comment: "Firstly, segments isn't isn't insert with an id, it's just inserted as a value" -> what do you mean by this? The JSON representation of an array will not show indices. If you want it as an object, you can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option of `json_encode`.

Comment: Please state what your code outputs, so we can compare with what you want to accomplice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same format as you use for the other items to get the same structure...

```
if (isset($querySegment)) {
    $arr['reportDescription']['segments'] = array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => $querySegment
            )
        );
}
```

As for the comma, this should be added automatically as needed if your using `json_encode()`

Comment: Thank you very much